# Remove outliers from a ggplotly() boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I have the dataframe below:

```
etf_id<-c("a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c","d","e")
factor<-c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C")
normalized<-c(-0.048436801,2.850578601,2.551666490,0.928625186,-0.638111793,
              -0.540615895,-0.501691539,-1.099239823,-0.040736139,-0.192048665,
              0.198915407,-0.092525810,0.214317734,2.550478998,0.024613778)
df<-data.frame(etf_id,factor,normalized)
```

and Im trying to remove outliers with 2 ways. First I try with `outlier.color = NA,outlier.size = 0,outlier.shape = NA`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
ggplotly(df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor, normalized, color = factor)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.color = NA,outlier.size = 0,outlier.shape = NA) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = quantile(df$normalized, c(0.01, 0.99), na.rm = T)))
```

Second example with diamonds dataset.

```
p<-ggplotly(diamonds %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cut,price, color = cut)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.color = NA,outlier.size = 0,outlier.shape = NA))
```

Then I try with:

```
ggplotly(df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor, normalized, color = factor)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.color = NA,outlier.size = 0,outlier.shape = NA) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = quantile(boxplot.stats(df$normalized)$stats[c(1, 5)]*1.5, c(0.01, 0.99), na.rm = T)))
```

but this way seems to cut my plot y limits and I need a generic solution.

Answer (score 3):

We can go under the hood of ggplotly object and make outliers invisible. However note that hovering over the invisible outliers will still show hoverinfo of the outlier measurements.

```
p<-ggplotly(diamonds %>% 
            ggplot(aes(cut,price, color = cut)) +
            geom_boxplot(outlier.color = NA,outlier.size = 0,outlier.shape = 
NA))

for(i in 1:length(p)){
p$x$data[[i]]$marker$opacity = 0 
}

p
```

[image: ggplotly boxplot no outlier]

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do with the second approach. However, for what it's worth, the issue you are facing is rooted in this part of the code: `boxplot.stats(df$normalized)$stats[c(1, 5)]*1.5`

Specifically, `boxplot.stats(df$normalized)$stats` returns this vector:

```
[1] -1.09923982 -0.34687010 -0.04073614  0.57147146  0.92862519
```

These are the boxplot stats (i.e. lower whisker, lower hinge, median, upper hinge, and upper whisker) for **ALL** of your data. But because the graph you are drawing is further subcategorizing the data by the `factor` variable, values from `boxplot.stats` for all of the data will not provide you with good boundaries.

Going back to your original problem of hiding outliers in boxplots: ggplotly does not honor the `outlier.shape = NA` argument you pass to ggplot. Instead, you should specifically hide the outliers in plotly. One solution can be found [on plotly's GitHub issue tracker here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1114).

Comment: the other issue is that it suppresses every point, not only outliers points.

Comment: In the example you provided, there is only one point and that is an outlier point. Please update the example so I can understand what the issue is.

Comment: yes that one point (2.55) should be removed. the same will be applied to the othe 2 boxplots if they have outliers

Comment: I added another example with diamonds dataset